# Name doesn't exist in the current context error happening in the same class

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple rock paper scissors game that uses keyboard input. I've realised that it's a better thing to type 1 for rock 2 for scissors etc than to write rock paper or scissors, but I want the console to write at the end what each player chose(rock, paper or scissors) instead of 1,2,3.

So when the string that has the number gets correct user input, another string 
becomes rock paper or scissors.However, although I'm only using one class and initialising `RealChoice1` and `RealChoice2` at the beginning of the while, I get the "name doesn't exist in the current context" error for both of them

```
while (true)
{
    string RealChoice2;
    string RealChoice1;

    while (true)
    {
        var key1 = System.Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (key1.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            break;

        Choice1 += key1.KeyChar;
    }


    if (Choice1 == "exit")
        return (int)ExitCode.UserInputExit;
    else if (Choice1 != "1" && Choice1 != "2" && Choice1 != "3")
            {
                Choice1 = null;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Please write 1, 2 or 3");
            }
            else if (Choice1 == "1" || Choice1 == "2" || Choice1 == "3")
                {
                    switch (Convert.ToInt32(Choice1))
                    {
                        case 1:
                            RealChoice1 = "Rock";
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            RealChoice1 = "Scissors";
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            RealChoice1 = "Paper";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
} //End of player 1 input


string Choice2 = null;
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Player2, please type what you choose");
//Player2Input:

while (true)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var key2 = System.Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key2.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            break;

        Choice2 += key2.KeyChar;
    }

    if (Choice2 == "exit")
        return (int)ExitCode.UserInputExit;
    else if (Choice2 != "1" && Choice2 != "2" && Choice2 != "3")
        {
            Choice2 = null;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Please write 1, 2 or 3");
        }
        else if (Choice2 == "1" || Choice2 == "2" || Choice2 == "3")
        {
            switch (Convert.ToInt32(Choice2))
            {
                case 1:
                    RealChoice2 = "Rock";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    RealChoice2 = "Scissors";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    RealChoice2 = "Paper";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Split the function into smaller ones and *don't* reuse variables in different scopes. It's very hard to find what's wrong in one long function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variables outside of the `while` loop if you want them to be available everywhere in the scope of your code.  Currently, since you're declaring them within the first `while` loop, they wouldn't be available where you're using them inside the second `while` loop.

Comment: While that will fix the immediate problem, the OP needs to split the code and *avoid* global variables. Otherwise the next question will be about unexpected variable values